# Scaling objects with a constant offset with geometry node

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes, mathematics

I'm looking to find a way to scale objects while maintaining a constant offset. I found a way to do it with two objects, but I don't know how I could do it with 3 or more.

> ex: (scale = 1) cube 1*1*1, cube 2*2*2 => (scale = 2) cube 2*2*2, cube
> 3*3*3 => (scale = 3) cube 3*3*3, cube 4*4*4,

Comment: I'm surprised that for you, the colleague's answer hit the mark and was marked as an "Accepted Answer", when in fact it's not optimal and is anything but procedural. Have you tried what I suggested here?

Comment: Your answer is far too specific. My question was for general use, and that other oh so simple method was perfect for the matter! I never used it to litterally scale cubes...

Comment: I understand your point of view, but exactly this answer leads the idea of a procedural 3D design ad absurdum. Therefore one should NOT solve such a concern with *Geometry Nodes* in exactly the same way. Whoever does it this way has not understood what GN is actually about, according to my professional opinion. And accepting an answer that solves your problem but does not show the optimal way with *Geometry Nodes* may lead others looking for an answer on wrong paths and gives wrong approaches. This is the point of my criticism.

Comment: Yes, your answer is brilliant, but there is dumb people like me who just don't get the basics right away... It was that kind of question, and needed that kind of answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the scale as the input value, use a math node to add to this value and then multiply for getting the scale.
[image]

Comment: It works fine for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

> You should always avoid to force with *Geometry Nodes* a solution, with which you must adapt everything again extremely individually to your task, but prefer instead always a solution, which solves you a certain task also actually **procedurally**.
>
> Otherwise, and this is the case with the answer of [Hezi Shahmoon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/260344/145249), you would lead the concept of *Geometry Nodes* ad absurdum and apply them wrongly.
>
> Even if this answer leads to the goal in your special case, it is not the optimal solution for this task and should be avoided.

So here's how you can solve it *correctly*:

### Blender 3.0+

[image]

1. Simply create a line with the number of objects you want. Define here for start point and end point the position $(0,0,0)$.
2. Then instantiate your cube with `Instance to Points` at these positions and use the index of the points as scaling.

### Blender 3.2

[image]

1. Convert a cube (or whatever) into an instance.
2. Duplicate the instance with `Duplicate Elements`.
3. Scale the instances with `Scale Instances`.